# Rails using incorrect Ruby in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Keep getting this error:

```
Could not find rake-10.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
/home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
```

And I have my profile as such:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM:
```

and whereis ruby gives me:

```
/usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
```

But I get the error that it's looking for ruby within tristan/.rvm/....

Any suggestions to have to change it to look for the usr rvm ruby?

Thanks!

```
tristan@kindidata:~/Kindidata$ bundle exec ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

and

```
tristan@kindidata:~/Kindidata$ bundle show rake
/home/tristan/Kindidata/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1
```

Also, why is the error from passenger looking for 1.9.3@global?!

Comment: Use rbenv for managing multiple ruby versions. It's simpler than rvm. Bundler can then be used to manage the different gems in a particular project https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Comment: please provide out put for commands: `rvm info`, then `bundle exec ruby -v`, and `bundle show rake`

Comment: You seem to have multuple versions of ruby installed at system, rvm level. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552313/1860929) answer if it helps.

Comment: Check rake versions with `gem list rake`, uninstall redundant versions and update your bundle

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have specified somewhere invalid version of [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), these places usually are: **.ruby-version**, **Gemfile**, **.rvmrc**. Verify all of these, and change all occurinces of [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) to *2.0.0*. Then reenter into the folder, and make sure that `rvm info` returns proper version of [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby). i.e. *2.0.0p247*:

```
rvm info|grep 'ruby:' -A 3 |grep 'version:'
    version:      "2.0.0p247"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

If that works then something is probably wrong with your rvm gem env variables.

Answer (score 0):

create .ruby-version file in your app folder with the below line

```
2.0.0p247
```

Comment: .rvmrc is deprecated for new rvm versions

Comment: containment of `.ruby-version` shall be just version

Comment: Is it OK. I need to try.