# Having trouble installing rails on Mac OS X (Yosemite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install rails on my Mac OS X (Yosemite). 
I get the following error:

```
Mohammads-iMac:~ mohammadriazi$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
installing rails:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes checking if the
C compiler accepts
-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no 
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries. checking for gzdopen() in
-lz... yes checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************ IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2 with the
following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
```

---

I did try updating gem, but I still get the error.
I have also installed home-brew

Please help! 
Thanks

Comment: You may want to patch ruby up to the latest version for yosemite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549107/which-ruby-version-am-i-really-running may be helpful

Comment: Don't install Rails into the system Ruby. Leave Apple's Ruby installation alone and instead use rbenv or RVM or Homebrew to install a separate Ruby, which you can then munge to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers guys!
I read this article here:
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x

It helped me understand rbenv.

- I then updated my rbenv and Homebrew to the latest version.
- Set my default ruby version to the latest version available.
  *(I guess the System Ruby installed on my MAC OS X was the default and this was causing the problem)*
- Finally I used gem to install the latest version of rails and then a rehash.

Everything works great now!
Thanks