# Using a particular Ruby version on a project

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use a specific version of ruby on a particular project. I looked into the RVM and rbenv packages, but had little success with any of them.

These are the steps I took:

- create project directory and navigate to it;
- run `rbenv install 2.3.1`; after navigating to ~/.rbenv/versions I can see a "2.3.1" in there;
- running "rbenv local" also echos 2.3.1;

My Gemfile is as follows:

```
ruby '2.3.1'

source 'https://rubygems.org/' do 
    gem 'test-kitchen'
    gem 'kitchen-terraform'
end
```

However, when I run `bundle install` i get the following error:

> Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1

Its my first time working with Ruby, so I am struggling a little. I appreciate all help, and can provide more details if required.

Comment: Your machine might be using system-ruby -- look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549107/which-ruby-version-am-i-really-running

Comment: Thank you for this link. It helped me uninstall the main ruby installation, and install it using rvm, which finally fixed the error. I guess I can install the most recent version with rvm again, and use both versions as I seam fit. Cheers mate.

Comment: > Its my first time working with Ruby
Not 100% clear, but if you're coming from a different language, you might also consider `asdf` or `anyenv` to manage Rubies since they have plugins for several other languages as well. Then, you can manage versions of multiple languages all at once

Answer (score 2):

If you store the ruby version of your project in `.ruby-version` and the gemset (i.e. gem list workspace) in `.ruby-gemset` of your project (which I recommend doing if the specific version is important to you), rvm should pick this up when you cd into your project directory. Sometimes it doesn't however depending on your setup or installation, in which case you can choose them explicitly with:

```
rvm use `cat .ruby-version`
rvm gemset use `cat .ruby-gemset
```

which I add to any installation scripts for example. You may need to run `gem install bundler` before running `bundle install` the first time you use the new gemset.

Answer (score 0):

Set your default rbenv version like this:

```
$ rbenv shell jruby-1.7.1
```

See in: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-shell